# array_merge changes the keys

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I got the following array:

```
$arr = array(6 => 'Somedata', 7 => 'Somedata1', 8 => 'Somedata2');
```

The problem is that, when I use `array_merge( (array) "Select the data", $arr);`, it does change the array keys into:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Not specified
    [1] => Somedata
    [2] => Somedata1
    [3] => Somedata2
)
```

Is that possible to skip the `array_merge` key preversion so the output would look like this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Not specified
    [6] => Somedata
    [7] => Somedata1
    [8] => Somedata2
)
```

Comment: please show us the code. `array_merge` is [preserving keys by default](http://codepad.org/I9YcWzdl)

Comment: @EXQStudio The code is in the second line of my question, there is a simple `array_merge( (array) "Select the data", $arr);` after, and `print_r` dump after that.

Comment: why do you cast string as array? Why not `Array("Select the data")`?

Comment: Array_merge preserves keys from the first array, couldn't you get the result you are after be switching the arrays around like: `array_merge($arr, (array) "Select the data");` ?

Comment: @EXQStudio Why not? See the http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php Example #1, its not forbidden, and working fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`+` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) to create a union of the 2 arrays:

```
$arr = array(6 => 'Somedata', 7 => 'Somedata1', 8 => 'Somedata2');

$result = (array)'Select the data' + $arr;

var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "Select the data"
  [6]=>
  string(8) "Somedata"
  [7]=>
  string(9) "Somedata1"
  [8]=>
  string(9) "Somedata2"
}
```

Comment: Be careful though, this can overwrite data if they arrays have the same key. Try running it with `$arr = array(0 => 'Somedata', 7 => 'Somedata1', 8 => 'Somedata2');` as the input.